# Is there a manual of how to write an Introduction?

Tags: thesis, masters, writing

I was reading a Introduction in a Master's thesis, and this particular example appears to be overly lengthy.

[image]

Is there a consensus on how many points can be adequately addressed in an introduction? or a maximum number of pages? or is this question fully subjective?

The goal here is to learn more about best approaches to writing an introduction, regardless of content.

Comment: See if improved after edited, would like know about manual of that whats not would should to be done.

Comment: This is dependent on the field and the type of publication/work, and more often than not, the journal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This example is from a Master's thesis, so the total number of pages is expected to be larger than, say, in a paper. Whether or not the length is appropriate depends on the quality of the text but, in general, I'd say it is fairly reasonable to have a 10-page-long thesis introduction (although each field has its own guidelines).

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no "manual" or restrictions on what can and cannot be done in writing the introduction of a paper or thesis. If there are any such restrictions, they are "local"—specific to a particular journal or department (in the case of a thesis or dissertation).

However, that doesn't mean that the example you cited is reasonable: however, without reading the associated content, it's hard to know for sure.